# Linux bash: How do I replace a string on a line based on a pattern on another/different line?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file that contains the following data:

```
GS*PO*112233*445566*20211006*155007*2010408*X*004010~

ST*850*0001~
BEG*00*DS*A-112233**20211005~
REF*K6*Drop Ship Order~
REF*ZZ*SO168219~
REF*DC*ABC~

ST*850*0002~
BEG*00*DS*A-44556**20211005~
REF*K6*Drop Ship Order~
REF*ZZ*PO54361~

ST*850*0003~
BEG*00*DS*A-12345**20211005~
REF*K6*Drop Ship Order~
REF*DC*XYZ~
REF*ZZ*SO897654~
```

For clarity, I have inserted blank line above each `ST*850` line. Here is what I want to do:

1. Search for the pattern `REF*ZZ*SO`
2. If found, then replace the preceding `ST*850` line with `ST*850C`

So the resultant file would look like this:

```
GS*PO*112233*445566*20211006*155007*2010408*X*004010~

ST*850C*0001~
BEG*00*DS*A-112233**20211005~
REF*K6*Drop Ship Order~
REF*ZZ*SO168219~
REF*DC*ABC~

ST*850*0002~
BEG*00*DS*A-44556**20211005~
REF*K6*Drop Ship Order~
REF*ZZ*PO54361~

ST*850C*0003~
BEG*00*DS*A-12345**20211005~
REF*K6*Drop Ship Order~
REF*DC*XYZ~
REF*ZZ*SO897654~
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
sed -i -n '/^REF\*ZZ\*SO/!{x;s/ST\*850\*/ST\*850C\*/;x};x;1!p;${x;p}' file
```

This replaces all the three `ST*850` lines with `ST*850C` and not just the 1st and the 3rd. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a `perl` solution although perl is not included in the tags.

```
perl -0777 -aF'(?=ST\*850)' -ne '
    print map {/REF\*ZZ\*SO/ && s/ST\*850/$&C/; $_} @F;
' file
```

Output:

```
GS*PO*112233*445566*20211006*155007*2010408*X*004010~

ST*850C*0001~
BEG*00*DS*A-112233**20211005~
REF*K6*Drop Ship Order~
REF*ZZ*SO168219~
REF*DC*ABC~

ST*850*0002~
BEG*00*DS*A-44556**20211005~
REF*K6*Drop Ship Order~
REF*ZZ*PO54361~

ST*850C*0003~
BEG*00*DS*A-12345**20211005~
REF*K6*Drop Ship Order~
REF*DC*XYZ~
REF*ZZ*SO897654~
```

- The `-0777` option tells `perl` to slurp whole file at once.
- The `-a` option enables the `auto split` mode then the split
  fragments are stored in the array `@F`.
- The `-F` option specifies the pattern to split the input.
- The regex `(?=ST\*850)` is a positive lookbehind which matches
  at the beginning of a string `ST*850`.
- The `-ne` option is mostly equivalent to that of `sed`.
- The `map {..} @F` function converts all elements of `@F` according
  to the statement within the curly brackets.
- The statement `/REF\*ZZ\*SO/ && s/ST\*850/$&C/` is translated as:
  "if the element of @F matches the pattern /REF*ZZ*SO/, then perform
  the substitution s/ST*850/$&C/ for the element."
- The final `$_` is the perl's default variable similar to the `pattern space` of sed and will be the return values of the map function.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/ST\*850/{:a;/REF\*ZZ\*SO/!{N;ba};s/.*ST\*850/&C/}' file
```

Begin gathering up lines if a line contains `ST*850`.

On matching a line that contains `REF*ZZ*SO` use greed to append `C` to the latest `ST*850` string.

N.B. The regexp `.*` ensures that the match will backtrack from the end of the collection rather than the start of the collection.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `ST` is essentially a record separator, you can use a simple Awk script to collect the lines in the current record, and print a modified different one if the conditions are right.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = RS = "\nST" }
    /REF\*ZZ\*SO/ { sub(/^\*850/, "*<850C") }1' filename
```

The `BEGIN` clause sets the record separator (`RS`) and also the output record separator (`ORS`) to the string `ST` preceded by a newline. (Attempting to include the asterisk got complicated, so I avoided that.) The final `1` is the common Awk shorthand for "print everything which reaches here".

`sed` is rather unwieldy for anything beyond simple line-based substitutions; I think you will find that switching to a higher-level language is going to improve maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

Preprocess with `sed` to insert new-lines then treat each block as an `awk` record, e.g.:

```
sed 's/^ST\*850/\n&/' | awk '/REF\*ZZ\*SO/ { sub(/ST\*850/, "&C") } 1' RS=
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your solution substitutes all occurrences is that you do not append the lines, you only swap back and forth between pattern and hold spaces. What you need is a kind of buffering until one or the other of the *special* lines are encountered. This is typically done by appending the pattern space to the hold space until a condition is fulfilled.

With `sed` (tested with GNU `sed`):

```
sed -n '/^ST\*850\*/{x;1!p;b};
        /^REF\*ZZ\*SO/{1!{H;x};s/ST\*850\*/ST*850C*/;p;b};
        1{h;b};H;${x;p}' file
```

- If it is a `ST*850*` line, swap pattern and hold spaces. Then, if it is not the first line, print. Start a new cycle. The hold space contains the `ST*850*` line. The preceding lines that were stored in the hold space, if any, have been printed.
- Else, if it is a `REF*ZZ*SO` line, swap pattern and hold spaces and do the substitution. Then, if it is not the first line, print. Start a new cycle. The hold space contains the `REF*ZZ*SO` line. The preceding lines that were stored in the hold space, if any, have been printed (after modification).
- Else, if it is the first line, replace the hold space by the pattern space and start a new cycle. The hold space thus contains the first line.
- Else append the pattern space to the hold space. If it is the last line swap pattern and hold spaces and print.

Comment: I tried this, but the last ```REF*ZZ*SO897654~``` is not printed

Comment: Ooops, you're right, I didn't realize that it wouldn't work if it was on the last line. I fix it but prefer the `sed` solution by potong, it is much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash: much more verbose but hopefully does not require any additional explanation.

```
#! /bin/bash

init_chunk()
{
  prefix=$1
  suffix=$2
  chunk=()
  refzzso=
}

print_chunk()
{
  if [[ ${#chunk[@]} > 0 ]]; then
    if [[ $refzzso == true ]]; then
      printf '%sC%s\n' "$prefix" "$suffix"
    else
      printf '%s%s\n' "$prefix" "$suffix"
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "${chunk[@]}"
  fi
}

init_chunk
while read -r line; do
  # Check for header.
  if [[ $line =~ ^(ST\*850)(.*) ]]; then
    # Print previous chunk.
    print_chunk
    # Begin new chunk.
    init_chunk "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    continue
  fi
  # Check if in a chunk.
  if [[ $prefix ]]; then
    # Check for modifier.
    if [[ $line =~ ^REF\*ZZ\*SO ]]; then
      refzzso=true
    fi
    chunk+=("$line")
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  fi
done
# Print last chunk.
print_chunk
```